# Background rendering and UI display

Tags: android, synchronization, rx-java, androidplot

My first attempt at AndroidPlot. The data I want to plot (and update every 5 seconds when a new data point arrives) comes from an `ArrayBlockingQueue` of up to 720 timestamped points. I have a class that implements the `XYSeries` and `PlotListener` interfaces. It has a method `updatePlotData` that just extracts the data from the queue into an array:

```
class TempPlotSeries implements XYSeries, PlotListener {
    private final static String TAG = TempPlotSeries.class.getSimpleName();
    private Pair<Date, Float>[] plotArray;
    void updatePlotData( ArrayBlockingQueue<Pair<Date, Float>> dataQueue ) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized ( this ) {
            wait();       // don't update data until we're notified that current plot is done (& we can get lock)
            plotArray = dataQueue.toArray( new Pair[0] );
            if( DEBUG ) Log.d( TAG, "updatePlotData run with " + plotArray.length + " data points" );
            notifyAll();  // release lock & let other threads know they can continue
        }
    }

    // XYSeries implementation
    @Override
    public int size( ) {
        return plotArray.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Number getX( int index ) {
        return (index - HISTORY_BUFFER_SIZE) / (60/TEMP_UPDATE_SECONDS);  // e.g., -60 minutes at left edge of graph, -1/12 min at right
    }
    @Override
    public Number getY( int index ) {
        return plotArray[index].second;  // the temp value
    }
    @Override
    public String getTitle( ) {
        return "Temp History";
    }

    // PlotListener Implementation
    @Override
    public void onBeforeDraw( Plot source, Canvas canvas ) {
        synchronized ( this ) {
            try {
                wait();  // wait for data updating to finish if it's in progress on another thread
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                // unlikely to be interrupted?
            }
        }
    }
    // between these 2 calls the plot is redrawn
    @Override
    public void onAfterDraw( Plot source, Canvas canvas ) {
        synchronized ( this ) {
            notifyAll( );  // plot done, OK to update data
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have much experience with synchronization--does this look reasonable?

My plot setup is:

```
tempHistoryPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.temp_history);
tempPlotSeries = new TempPlotSeries();
tempHistoryPlot.setRenderMode( Plot.RenderMode.USE_BACKGROUND_THREAD );
tempGraphFormatter = new LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels);
tempHistoryPlot.addSeries(tempPlotSeries, tempGraphFormatter);
tempGraphWidget = tempHistoryPlot.getGraph();
```

(couldn't find any documentation on the purpose of `getGraph()` so don't know if I need it.)

I have an `Observable` (RxJava) that emits the entire data queue when a new sample is available (every 5 seconds). If the queue is full I discard the oldest value. Then I have:

```
    tempPlotSeries.updatePlotData( newTempHistory );
    tempHistoryPlot.redraw();
```

But the plot isn't drawn. When the app first launches, the "dummy" plot appears in its View, but as soon as I try to draw the plot the entire `ConstraintLayout` containing the `XYPlot` element (and other UI elements) is completely blanked. What's going on here?

Other questions: it's my understanding that any code affecting the Android UI must run on the main thread. But we're using a background thread to render the plot. How does this work? Do I perhaps need to insert a `.observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` operator in my Observable chain?

Comment: Update: I discovered that adding the `.observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` to the chain stops the erasing of the UI, but it doesn't draw anything and now appears to freeze the app.

Comment: Removing the `wait()` and `notifyAll()` in `updatePlotData()` fixed the freeze but still doesn't draw anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have much experience with synchronization--does this look reasonable?

I don't think you need the `wait()` inside the synchronized block inside `updatePlotData`.  You can also use [SimpleXYSeries](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/xy/SimpleXYSeries.java) as a reference for how to setup synchronization of this sort.

> When the app first launches, the "dummy" plot appears in its View, but as soon as I try to draw the plot the entire ConstraintLayout containing the XYPlot element (and other UI elements) is completely blanked.

I'm having trouble visualizing this.  Could you add a screenshot of the "dummy" plot and the subsequent blank plot?

> it's my understanding that any code affecting the Android UI must run on the main thread. But we're using a background thread to render the plot. How does this work?

The general rules of using the main thread to update the UI still exist, Androidplot is just using a technique to minimize the main thread usage during intensive rendering: A background thread is used to fill a bitmap buffer with the data to be shown, then notifies the main thread when the buffer is ready to be displayed.

Somewhat Unrelated Suggestion:  Looking at your `TempPlotSeries` implementation, I notice that you are modeling your data as a `Pair<Date, Float>[]` but your `getX()` implementation does not make use of the `Date` part.  It appears you're trying to model your data using what I assume is your desired display format for your domain, ie.  -60 to -1/12 minutes.  For simplicity I'd suggest making `getX()` return the Date's long epoch value instead.  You can apply a display format to these values later.

Comment: Thank you. As for formatting the X axis, I don't want actual dates displayed, just "minutes before right now". I'm keeping the timestamps for possible use elsewhere. In any case this shouldn't hurt anything except maybe slow it down a bit, right? Unfortunately none of this answers the question of why nothing is being drawn (and do I need the `getGraph()`?). I misspoke about the "dummy" plot: it actually appears when I look at the layout resource in Android Studio; when the app runs I see only a black rectangle.

Comment: I removed all the `wait()` and `notifyAll()` statements and it still doesn't draw anything. Just a solid black rectangle—no axes or labels or anything. Question: do I have to somehow do an initial draw before I call `tempHistoryPlot.redraw()`?

Comment: Nope shouldnt need to do anything special before calling redraw.  As a quick troubleshooting step, could you try disabling background rendering mode to see if that makes any difference?  Should be as simple as removing this line from your layout: `ap:renderMode="use_background_thread"`

Comment: also are you seeing your "updatePlotData run with..." debug statement firing every  5 seconds?

Comment: regarding minutes before right now - thats easy enough to calculate for display purposes from a long timestamp.  it's just (now - timestamp) / 60000. generally speaking there are far fewer display labels than there are data points in a series, so doing it this way avoids needless math on every single point in the series, but if what you have works for you then i wouldnt worry about it too much.

Comment: Yes the "updatePlotData run…" is getting logged. However, when I remove the background thread option, the app crashes immediately with "attempt to get length of null array" when the `size()` method of my `XYSeries` implementation is called. Guess I need to look at that some more. (Does it make sense that this doesn't cause a problem on a background thread?)

Comment: Most likely you're not initializing your series' plotArray property until you your background thread loops the first time.  In bg mode its not a problem because the plot doesn't redraw until you tell it to.  I think if you initialize `plotArray` to an empty array instead of null it should get you past that.

Comment: Wow, it was working until I replaced the "background thread" option. Then nothing.

Comment: Trying to understand the docs, but is there a simple way to disable text labeling of data points on the graph?

Comment: I figured out the text labeling but do you have any idea why it works with background thread disabled, and not with it enabled? Also, instead of seeing a simple series of data points connected by line segments, I'm seeing what looks more like a "high-low-close" graph: vertical line segments at each point, with the left and right connecting lines intersecting the vertical segment at different points.